# Boost Socket goes belly-up on close()

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

We have a C++ application that talks to a server. It sends two messages to it, and the server responds to each message with another message. We're using Boost, but the Boost Socket--the entire application--barfs when we attempt to close the socket.

Here's the general idea of what we're doing:

1. encode the message (change it into a string)
2. open socket
3. send message
4. check the bytes sent
5. check the return message
6. shutdown & close the socket

Since we send two messages, we do it in a loop (just two iterations, obviously).

We know exactly where the error is since, if we remove that line, it works fine. It's on step 5. Unfortunately, that's kind of an important step. We can't find what we're doing wrong  how to fix it.

Here's the code:

```
bool ReallyImportantService::sendMessages( int messageNum ) {

    // ...some error-checking here...

    bool successCode = false;
    for( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {

        successCode = false;

        unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> theSocket = connect();

        if( theSocket == nullptr ) {
            theLogger->error( "Could not create socket, could not send input messageNum to service" );
            return successCode;
        }

        string message = encodeMessage( messageNum );

        // send the message
        boost::system::error_code error;
        size_t bytesSent = boost::asio::write(*theSocket,
                                       boost::asio::buffer(message),
                                       boost::asio::transfer_all(), error);

        // inspect the result
        if( !messageNumSendSuccessful(message.length(), bytesSent) ) {
            return successCode;
        }

        // Get the response message
        string response;
        boost::system::error_code e;
        boost::asio::streambuf buffer;

        // this is step #5 above, the line that kills it. But it responds with no errors
        boost::asio::read_until(*theSocket, buffer, "\0", e);

        if( e.value() == boost::system::errc::success ) {
            istream str(&buffer);
            getline(str, response);

            // validate response
            successCode = messageAckIsValid( response, messageNum );
        }
        else {
            theLogger->error( "Got erroneous response from server when sending messageNum" );
        }

        // close it all up
        boost::system::error_code eShut;
        theSocket->shutdown(boost::asio::socket_base::shutdown_type::shutdown_both, eShut);
        // We never get an error code here, all clean

        try {
            boost::system::error_code ec;

            // This is where it all goes belly-up. It doesn't throw an exception, doesn't return an 
            // error-code. Stepping through, we can see the call stack shows a Segmentation fault, 
            // but we don't know what could be causing this.
            theSocket->close( ec );
        }
        catch(boost::system::system_error& se) {
            theLogger->error( "sendMessages() barfed on close! " + string(se.what()) );
        }
        catch( ... ) {
            theLogger->error( "sendMessages() barfed on close! " );
        }
    }
    return successCode;
}

string ReallyImportantService::encodeMessage( int messageNum ) {

    // Encode the message
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "^FINE=";
    ss << to_string(messageNum) << "\n";
    string message = ss.str();

    theLogger->info( message );

    return message;
}

unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> ReallyImportantService::connect() {
    // Addresses from configuration
    string address( server_ip );
    string port( server_port );

    // Resolve the IP address
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ioService);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(address, port);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator ep_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    // create the socket
    unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> theSocket = make_unique<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(ioService);

    // not sure if this is necessary, but couldn't hurt; we do reuse the IP address the second time around
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    theSocket->set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true), ec);

    // Connect
    try {

        boost::asio::connect(*theSocket, ep_iterator);

    } catch(const boost::system::system_error &e){
        theSocket = nullptr;
        theLogger->error( "Exception while attempting to create socket: " + string(e.what()) );
    } catch(const exception &e){
        theSocket = nullptr;
        theLogger->error( "Exception while attempting to create socket: " + string(e.what()) );
    }

    return theSocket;
}
```

Here's the call stack we get when it errors-out:

```
(Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault)   
    pthread_mutex_lock() at 0x7ffff7bc8c30  
    boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex::lock() at posix_mutex.hpp:52 0x969072 
    boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex>::scoped_lock() at scoped_lock.hpp:36 0x980b66    
    boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::free_descriptor_state() at epoll_reactor.ipp:517 0x96c6fa   
    boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::deregister_descriptor() at epoll_reactor.ipp:338 0x96bccc   
    boost::asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::close() at reactive_socket_service_base.ipp:103 0xb920aa 
    boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::close() at stream_socket_service.hpp:151 0xb975e0 
    boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::close() at basic_socket.hpp:339 0xb94f0d    
    ReallyImportantService::sendMessages() at ReallyImportantService.cc:116 0xb8ce19    
    <...more frames...>
```

We created a minimal implementation that just:

1. Creates the socket
2. Shuts down the socket
3. Closes the socket

And it works perfectly. We put it in a loop and we can go for dozens of iterations without any problems.

We're using Eclipse CDT and gcc to compile.

Any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've broken the cardinal rule.

An `io_service` must outlive all objects created on it.

Your `connect()` function creates an `io_service`, creates a socket on it and returns the socket (wrapped in a unique_ptr). Then the `io_service` is destroyed.

From that point forward, all bets are off because the socket will use a the socket service object associated with the io_service you just destroyed. This socket service is now just memory with undefined values in it. You're (un)lucky the program got this far before the segfault.

In general you will need one `io_service` per application. All objects that need it should carry a reference to it.

Your connect function then becomes:

```
bool connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp& theSocket) {
    // Addresses from configuration
    string address( server_ip );
    string port( server_port );

    // Resolve the IP address
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(theSocket.get_io_service());
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(address, port);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator ep_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    // not sure if this is necessary, but couldn't hurt; we do reuse the IP address the second time around
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    theSocket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true), ec);

    // Connect
    try {

        boost::asio::connect(theSocket, ep_iterator);

    } catch(const boost::system::system_error &e){
        theSocket = nullptr;
        theLogger->error( "Exception while attempting to create socket: " + string(e.what()) );
        return false;
    } catch(const exception &e){
        theSocket = nullptr;
        theLogger->error( "Exception while attempting to create socket: " + string(e.what()) );
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool sendMessages(boost::asio::io_service& ios, int messageNum)
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket theSocket(ios);
    auto ok = connect(theSocket);

    // ... carry on ...

}
```

- Prefer to hold references to sockets etc whenever possible. Wrapping them in a `unique_ptr` is a confusing extra layer of indirection.
- As of c++11 and recent versions of boost, asio sockets are moveable. You can return them by value as opposed to passing in a reference as I have done.
- I notice that you have a mixture of exception and non-exception error handling in the code. You probably want to stick to one or the other (in my view exception-based error handling is cleaner, but this is not a universal view).

Comment: That worked! We don't have much experience with Boost--we inherited this code--so didn't know about the need for a persistent io_service. Now we know, and can go forth boldly with more knowledge. Thank you!

Comment: @Frecklefoot some essential reading here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core.html
The asio documentation is famously terse. Suggest reading it more than a few times - at least it took me a number of readings to understand all the nuances.